# Showing error message after Tomcat LockOutRealm error / user lock

Tags: tomcat, authentication, tomcat8, jdbcrealm

I'm using JDBCRealm + [LockOutRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/LockOutRealm.html) in Tomcat (8, but could switch to 9). This is working all fine, but if a user locks himself out, this is only visible in the logs, not the user facing login error page.

Imagine a user entering his or her password with caps locks on a few times, therefore locking the account, then noticing the caps lock, removing it and still not being able to log in.

**Is there a way to show that the LockOutRealm and not a wrong password is the reason for the unsuccessful logon?**

I only do see this in catalina.out:

```
Aug 24, 2018 10:59:15 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm authenticate
WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "abcd"
Aug 24, 2018 10:59:15 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Failed authenticate() test ??/test/j_security_check
```

I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621889/175200), which IMHO is the only related answer in the area. But it is from 2011 and there might be a better and easier way to do this now.

Also (way less important), is there a way to unlock a user from an application account / reset LockOutRealm, e.g. by accessing some protected servlet, that does this, with an Admin account? There is an *unlock()* method, but it does not seem it is designed to be used from within the application, see [here](https://coderanch.com/t/648341/application-servers/Tomcat-LockOutRealm-unlock-method-code).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem. Nothing seems to have have changed. To add another workaround, I ended up getting the LockOutRealm via reflection, as described [here](http://tipsaboutmywork.blogspot.com/2012/06/get-realm-or-loginservice-instance-from.html).
Of course, this violates the design principle that the app is not supposed to know which realms are in use.

Relevant code:

```java
 ApplicationContextFacade acf = (ApplicationContextFacade) request.getSession().getServletContext();

 Field privateField = ApplicationContextFacade.class.getDeclaredField("context");  
 privateField.setAccessible(true);  
 ApplicationContext appContext = (ApplicationContext) privateField.get(acf);
  
 Field privateField2 = ApplicationContext.class.getDeclaredField("context");  
 privateField2.setAccessible(true);  
 StandardContext stdContext = (StandardContext) privateField2.get(appContext);
  
 LockOutRealm realm = (LockOutRealm) stdContext.getRealm();
```

Then use `realm.isLocked(username)` to decide which error message to show.
(LockOutRealm might not be the root realm, this depends on the configuration in context.xml)